# How to rebuild dependencies before running jetty from maven

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a multi module maven project. One of the modules is a reusable part which is packaged into a jar, and the other is a war web-app which depends on the first module. When I use jetty:run-exploded on the second module, the packaged jar is taken from local maven repository whereas I want the first module to be rebuild and packaged into the resulting war. Is there any way to force such behavior instead of the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything I can tell from reading documents about Maven's design and using Maven myself this cannot be done in the projects own directory.

Maven will not follow module paths UP a hierarchy. Using -amd (also make dependencies) will only work at the top level module that ties all the other multi-module pom's together. So what you can do is this:

At the TOP level directory

`mvn -amd -pl jetty_module jetty:run-exploded`

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov What issue are you experiencing?

Comment: If I run the command without anything installed, the error is reported. If I run with the dependency in the repo, the dependency in the repo used instead of the local module. It seems that -amd means also make depenendent and we should use -am instead. However, if I use -am, I can't call jetty:run-exploded.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Seems to me like your top level POM doesn't have all the child module's in it in order for Maven to determine dependencies. Can you do "mvn clean install" at the top level and it builds everything ok?

Comment: Nothing helped, unfortunately.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Please feel free to e-mail me so we can take this offline.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use maven Advanced Reactor Options to archive this.

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

> The -pl or –projects option allows you to select a list of projects from a multimodule project. This option can be useful if you are working on a specific set of projects, and you’d rather not wait through a full build of a multi-module project during a development cycle.

Maven -amd(also-make-dependents ) also help to build multi module project once. Using that you can build a project and any project that depends on that project.

Comment: But how can I run jetty:run-exploded from the containing project? Building the whole project isn't a big deal, I just don't want to call mvn package for the container module and then mvn jetty:run-jetty for the submodule. I want to merge this two steps into one action.

Comment: How about mvn install jetty:run, it will can used to build your project and start jetty server.

Comment: @Chandana I need to call install and jetty:run for different projects. install for the container, and jetty:run for war subproject